# Specific CSS for JavaFX web view

Tags: css, javafx, webview

If you are loading a webpage with JavaFX webview is it possible in CSS to have it show up with certain formatting different to how it would normally show up in other browsers and devices? Would you embed this CSS into your java code? If so, how would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can load a css file to WebView. This CSS behaves same way in both traditional browsers as well as web view.

#### adding stylesheets to webview

```
    stage.setTitle("Web View");
    scene = new Scene(new Browser(),750,500, Color.web("#666970"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css");        
    stage.show();
```

#### Full example

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class WebViewSample extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create the scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(),750,500, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css");        
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
class Browser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        //apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");
        // load the web page
        webEngine.load("http://www.oracle.com/products/index.html");
        //add the web view to the scene
        getChildren().add(browser);

    }
    private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }

    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h,0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 750;
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 500;
    }
}
```

for more details, please refer [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm)